# Second constructor when standard constructor has superfluous information

Tags: python, constructor

I have the following situation:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, O):
         self.a = O.some_attr.calc_a()
         self.b = O.some_other_attr.calc_b()
```

Note that `O` *cannot* be reconstructed from `a` and `b`. Now, I also want to be able to initialise `Foo` directly by passing `a` and `b`, but I only want to do this internally, the standard way should be by passing `O`.

I know I can do something like

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def from_O(cls, O):
        return cls(O.some_attr.cal_a(), O.some_other_attr.cal_b())
```

but this has the disadvantage that the *standard* call now becomes the more cumbersome `Foo.from_O(O)`.

In other words, how can I achieve `Foo(O)` and `Foo.from_a_b(a,b)` when `O` is *not* reconstructable from `a` and `b`?
Can I have a classmethod that avoids calling `__init__`?

(Note: I am looking for a 'clean' way to do this. I know I can dissect the argument list or do  something like

```
class _Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Foo(_Foo):
    def __init__(self, O):
        super().__init__(O.some_attr.cal_a(), O.some_other_attr.cal_b())
```

but this seems a rather awkward solution.)

Comment: The `classmethod` use of `from_` something is quite common is explicit that you're actually wanting to use a certain type of object... `__init__` is used for direct values... mixing the two would be weird... your *I know I can do something like* approach is the Pythonic way of doing this and doing otherwise is actually just more confusing

Comment: (you end up otherwise trying to working what to do if you want mix an `a` from one source directly and `b` from a calculated source... and what happens if passing both etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You could make `O`, `a`, and `b` all optional arguments to the same `__init__` method and make a distinction on whether `O` is given or not.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, O=None, a=None, b=None):
         if O is not None:
             self.a = O.some_attr.calc_a()
             self.b = O.some_other_attr.calc_b()
             # ignore a and b
         else:
             if a is None or b is None:
                 raise TypeError("If O is not given, a and b cannot be None")
             self.a = a
             self.b = b
```

Usage:

```
# from O
foo_from_O = Foo(O)

# from a, b
foo_from_a_b_1 = Foo(None, 'a', 'b')
foo_from_a_b_2 = Foo(a='a', b='b')
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm afraid this is essentially what 'dissect the argument list' was referring to.

Comment: at the end of the day @Jonathan like I've said in comments above... what you tried is the best what to do this... otherwise, you just end up adhoc'ing stuff